# Why are some of my teasers only show up inside the view preview and not on the page?

Tags: 7, views

I've got a view that is displaying a couple different content types in teaser form. Everything looks fine in the view preview but when I look at the actual page, only one content type is displaying the teaser. I've tried comparing them and don't see any differences that would make any difference. Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

This is a screenshot of my view.

> [image: screenshot]

Comment: Could it be caused by the theme you're using? You can check that by switching back to a core theme like Bartik or Stark. If that makes the expected content show up, the problem is probably in your template.php or in a .tpl.php file.

Answer (score 0):

For each content type, go to "manage display" and then "Teaser". Make sure all the fields in there are set the same way as the content type that is working.

Comment: I checked that but they're both set up the same.